# Can I test wayland on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, wayland

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.8.0-50-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega Graphics
Memory: 29.4 GiB of RAM

I have tried following advice for Ubuntu desktops, but that doesn't seem to apply to Kubuntu.
I have some strange video issues where random x-windows stop updating or repainting the screen. It happens when watching videos with SMPlayer and VLC and in Firefox and Thunderbird. Even the plasma panel will get in on the action with flickering titles or the digital clock will stop working.
I have to change any of the Compositor settings to get windows to start updating again. Turning off the Compositor accomplishes nothing. I'm not finding any help for these issues so thought of trying out Wayland. Will I have to update to 21.04 before I will be able to start a Wayland session?

Comment: That was not the question.

Comment: This is why I do not ask for help here as a rule.

Comment: It seems you did ask a question, and since the literal question you ask has a rather trivial answer but will not solve your problem, I thought trying to get to your real problem would be more helpful. But forget that and read the answer to what you literally asked.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.
You need to install `plasma-workspace-wayland`

```
sudo apt install plasma-workspace-wayland
```

logout and log back in selecting the plasma wayland session.